# Group algebra of a quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-rings

> **[Definition]** Let $K$ be a field and $G$ be a group. Group algebra $K[G]$ is the set of all linear combinations of finitely many elements of $G$ with coefficients in $K$.

If we are given a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, since the quotient $G/N$ is also a group we can consider group algebra $K(G/N)$. I want to know the relationship between $KG$ and $K(G/N)$. I suppose $K(G/N)$ is a quotient group of $KG$, for example $K(G/N)\simeq KG/KN$. I'm not sure if my supposition is true. Can anyone explain this in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider the projection map

$\pi: G\to G/N$

that induces a natural morphism of algebra

$\pi’: KG\to K(G/N)$

that maps each polynomial $p=\sum_{g\in G}k_gg$, $|\{k_g: k_g\neq 0\}|<\infty$, to the polynomial

$\pi’(p):=\sum_{g\in G}k_ggN$

This map is clearly surjective. We consider $p\in K_N$, $\sum_{h\in N}k_hh$. Then

$\pi’(p)= \sum_{h\in N}k_hhN=\left(\sum_{h\in N}k_h\right)N$

that is not zero in general. This means that we must consider the quotient

$K\left(G/N\right)/(N)$

In this case we get that

$KN\subseteq \ker(\pi’)$

where $\pi’$ is defined as

$\pi’:KG\to K\left(G/N\right)/(N)$

Now we consider a polynomial $p\in KG$, $p=\sum_{g\in G}k_g g$,  such that $\pi’(p)=0$. Then there exists $\lambda \in K$ for which

$\sum_{g\in G}k_g gN=\lambda N$

So

$ \sum_{g\not \in N}k_ggN+\left(\sum_{g\in N}k_g-\lambda\right)N=$

$=\sum_{g\not \in N}k_ggN+\sum_{g\in N}k_gN-\lambda N$

$=\sum_{g\in G}k_g gN-\lambda N=0$

This means that

$k_g=0$ for each $g\not \in N$ and

$\sum_{g\in N}k_g=\lambda$

So

$p=\sum_{g\in G}k_gg=\sum_{g\in N}k_gg\in KN$

In other way we have $\ker(\pi’)=KN$. This implies

$KG/KN\cong K\left(G/N\right)/(N)$

Comment: Maybt its worth to stress that in the expression $KG/KN$ the term $KN$ is not the group-algebra, but the ideal of $KG$ generated by $KN$. Otherwise the dimensions would not match. In general one never wants to take a quotient of a ring by a sub-ring, but only by an ideal.

Comment: @HenrikRueping oh, thanks you very much. You’re right

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I need a reference for my work. Is this isomorphism equivalence a theorem with a special name ? I need the name. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know a reference for this work, I am sorry. And I don't know if the isomorphism has a name :(

Comment: @Federico: it's not the ideal of $K[G]$ generated by $K[N]$ either. You want the ideal generated by $\{ n - 1 : n \in N \}$.